# Convert cell text in progressive number

Tags: sql, matlab, postgresql

I have written this SQL in PostgreSQL environment:

```
SELECT
    ST_X("Position4326") AS lon,
    ST_Y("Position4326") AS lat,
    "Values"[4] AS ppe,
    "Values"[5] AS speed,
    "Date" AS "timestamp",
    "SourceId" AS smartphone,
    "Track" as session
FROM
    "SingleData"
WHERE
    "OsmLineId" = 44792088
AND
    array_length("Values", 1) > 4
AND
    "Values"[5] > 0
ORDER BY smartphone, session;
```

Now I have imported the result in Matlab and I have six vectors and one cell (because the text from the UUIDs was converted in cell) all of 5710x1 size.

Now I would like convert the text in the cell, in a progressive number, like 1, 2, 3... for each different session code.

In Excel it is easy with `FIND.VERT(obj, matrix, col)`, but I do not know how do it in Matlab.

Now I have a big cell with a lot of codes like:

`ff95465f-0593-43cb-b400-7d32942023e1`

I would like convert this cell in an array of numbers where at the first occurrence of

`ff95465f-0593-43cb-b400-7d32942023e1` -> 1

and so on. And you put 2 when a different code appear, and so on.

Comment: I don't understand what the expected output should look like can you post a small example?

Comment: I have add an example.

Comment: Ok, so the same code can appear more than once in the cell `session` right?

Comment: Exactly. You can solve with `IndexC = strfind(C,'dc70ae68-f31d-4e94-8b3b-9d73ee662fe9');` and `Index = find(not(cellfun('isempty', IndexC)));` but I need a step: convert the `cell(1234,1)` into array for strfind.

Comment: The code above work, but if I use `IndexC = strfind(C, session(1234,1);` I obtain: **Error using cell/strfind (line 33)
If any of the input arguments are cell arrays, the first must be a cell array of strings and the second must
be a character array.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I have solve.

I put the single `session` code in a second cell `C`.

At this point, with a for loop, I obtain:

```
%% Converting of the UUIDs into integer
C = unique(session);
N = length(session);

session2 = zeros(N, 1);
for i = 1:N
    session2(i) = find(strcmp(C, session(i)));
end
```

Thanks to all!

Comment: Yup that's why I said "when you're allowed to" :)

Comment: Sorry, I am not native English.